# Успешность выполнения миссий Бонда

Tags: алгоритм

Нашёл одну интересную задачу. Буду думать над решением и неплохо бы услышать ваши предложения:

> Каждый месяц Джеймс Бонд получает список миссий. Основываясь на своем богатом опыте, он вычисляет вероятность успешного выполнения миссий каждой из своих кузин Джими Бонд номер X.
>
> Ваша программма должна обработать эти данные и найти такое разделение миссий между кузинами, чтобы получить наибольшую вероятность того, что все миссии будут успешно выполнены.
>
> Замечение: вероятность того, что все миссии будут успешно выполнены, равна произведению вероятностей того, что отдельные миссии будут выполнены успешно.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> Первая строка содержит целое число N - количество миссий (1 <= N <= 20). Следующие N строк содержат по N целых чисел от 0 до 100, включительно. j-тое целое число на i-той строке означает вероятность того, что кузина i выполнит успешно миссию j. Вероятность задана в процентах.
>
> Формат вывода
>
> Выведите максимальную вероятность успешного выполнения всех миссий, в процентах.
>
> Вывод отличающийся от официального ответа не более чем на +0.000001, будет принят.
>
> Примеры
>
> ```
> input        input       input    
> 2            2           3        
> 100 100      0 50        25 60 100
> 50 50        50 0        13 0 50  
>                            12 70 90 
>
> output       output      output
> 50.000000    25.00000    9.10000
> ```
>
> Пояснение к 3-му примеру:
>
> Если Джимми 1 назначить 3-ю миссию, Джимми 2 назначить 1-ую миссию, а Джимми 3 назначить 2-ую миссию, то получим вероятность успеха равную 1.0 * 0.13 * 0.7 = 0.091 = 9.1%. Все другие варианты распределения миссий дают меньшую вероятность успеха.

***P. S.*** Вопрос к администрации: я частенько решаю задачи такого типа (спортивное программирование) и, если я их буду предлагать для решения (тоже часто) на этом форуме, то не будете ли вы считать, что я зафлудил ваш сайт, и не последует ли за этим бан?

Comment: Мне кажется, действительно интересные алгоритмические задачи - это хорошо. Единственное, рекомендовал бы писать более содержательный заголовок, иначе на портале будут десятки вопросов с заглавием "Интересная задача" или "Есть ли другие решения", среди которых найти интересующую будет очень сложно.

Comment: Часом задача не на минимакс? Я в первом приближении делал так:
1) нашел бы максимальную вероятность. Отметил бы ее. 
2) уменьшил бы таблицу на эту строчку и на этот столбец.
3) провел бы процесс для оставшейся части таблицы.
Таким образом я получу максимальное произведение. Т.к. каждый член будет максимален.
Если при переходе между п.1 и п.2 будет ситуация, что максимальная вероятность встречается несколько раз, то, очевидно, что выгодно выбрать ту строчку, в которой остальные вероятности хуже.

Comment: Т.е. из 25 60 100 и 26 59 100 надо выбрать вторую, чтобы получилось 1.00*0.6, иначе макс. получим 1.00*0.59, что хуже.
Проверяйте и высказывайте свои предложения по такому ходу мыслей =)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы предлагаете по сути жадную стратегию. Я уже на эти грабли наступил - она не работает. Достаточно представить случай, когда в конце остается нулевая вероятность, которая убивает нафиг весь жадный выигрыш. Судя по всему здесь нужно использовать стратегию типа динамического программирования, сводя эту задачу к решению задач меньшей размерности. Может, завтра на свежую голову оформлю эту мысль подробней.

Comment: М-да, действительно, тогда получится облом. Тогда на 0-м этапе нужно отсеять все нулевые вероятности.

Comment: Дело не в нулевых вероятностях (просто пример самый очевидный). Представьте 4 числа a > b > c > d. a*d легко может оказаться меньше b*c. Этого жадная стратегия не учитывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде придумал. Сегодня вечером протестирую и сообщю результаты.

Решение:

> ДП по битовым маскам. Будем хранить в массиве **f** ответы меньшей размерности на нашу задачу. Индексы **f** - распределения миссий для кузин.
>
> Рассмотрим **f[i]**. Посмотрим на двоичное представление числа **i**. Например i = 100110.

```
|**№ бита**  | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
|------------+---+---+---+---+---+---|
|**знач. i** | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
```

> Это значит что в **f[i]** находится ответ, и если дали задание кузине с номером **k**, то **k**-ый бит равен 1. Причём, если количество ненулевых битов в числе **i** равно 3, то мы распределили кузин для первых 3 миссий.

Конкретней реализация:

> Перебираем все маски (от 0 до 2^20 - 1 ~ 10^6), представляющие наше распределение (1).
> Для каждой маски считаем количество единиц в ней - это количество распределённых миссий **м**(2).
> Смотрим: какие кузины у нас не выполняют никаких заданий (3).
> Пробуем назначить какой-нибудь кузине задание **v+1**. (4)
> всё

**a[i, j]** - вероятность выполнения миссии **j** кузиной **i**

```
    for msk := 0 to pow[n] - 1 do begin //pow[w] = 2^w; (1)
            v := q(msk); //(2)
            for i := 1 to n do // перебираем всех кузин
                    if msk and pow[i-1] = 0 then //(3)
                            f[msk or pow[i-1]] := max(f[msk or pow[i-1]],f[msk]*a[v+1,i]);// (4)
    end;
```

> ответ получим, когда распределили всех кузин, т. е. все биты = 1 (f[2^n-1]).

Таким образом решение работает за N*2^N ~ 20.000.000 (< 1 секунды будет выполнятся алгоритм).

Полный код:

```
const
        maxN     = 21;
        maxS     = 1 shl maxN;   
var
        n,m,i,j,msk,v   : longint;    
        a               : array [1..maxN,1..maxN] of double;    
        f               : array [1..maxS] of double;    
        pow             : array [0..maxN] of longint;    
function q(w : longint) : longint;
        var
                res     : longint;
        begin
                res := 0;
                while w > 0 do begin
                        if w and 1 = 1 then
                                inc(res);
                        w := w shr 1;
                end;
                q := res;
        end;    
function max(w1,w2 : double) : double;
        begin
                if w1 > w2 then
                        max := w1
                else
                        max := w2;
        end;    
begin
        readln(n);

        for i := 1 to n do
                for j := 1 to n do begin
                        read(a[i,j]);
                        a[i,j] := a[i,j] / 100;
                end;

        pow[0] := 1;
        for i := 1 to maxN do
                pow[i] := pow[i-1] shl 1;

        for i := 1 to n do
                f[pow[i-1]] := a[1,i];
 
        for msk := 0 to pow[n] - 1 do begin
                v := q(msk);
                for i := 1 to n do
                        if msk and pow[i-1] = 0 then
                                f[msk or pow[i-1]] := max(f[msk or pow[i-1]],f[msk]*a[v+1,i]);
        end;

        writeln(f[pow[n]-1]*100:0:10);
end.
```

Comment: УРА! Протестировал - абсолютно правильное решение!

Answer (score 0):

У меня нет возможности комментировать(мало репутации), поэтому даю ответом. Какие ограничения на скорость алгоритма? Можно попробовать перебором. Если число кузин(X) == числу миссий, то всего вариантов X!. Можно перебирать все числа от 1 до X^X, переводить их в X-ичную систему счисления(например функцией itoa(number, outString, X)), затем разбить число на цифры(Цифра будет скажем номером кузины которая делает миссию с номером равным порядковому номеру цифры в числе), если какие-то 2 цифры одинаковые, то сразу переходим к следующей итерации цикла, иначе считаем общую вероятность и записываем в глобальную переменную max.

Да, решение некрасиво и неэффективно, но это первое что пришло в голову. При большом количестве кузин будет очень долго считать, но зато надёжно.

Comment: Простое решение я уже написал. Но мне нужно "красивое и эффективное"!

Comment: ограничение по времени 1 секунда.